# What are these succulents in a decorative pot?

Tags: identification, plant-recommendations, plant-care, succulents

[image]

[image]

I got these awesome plants but I don't know what they are or how to care for them. Can you help me?

Comment: Have you only just received these plants? Or have you had it a while?

Comment: Whatever you do do not water hardly ever.  Only when your pot is light to lift.  Are you able to ask if these plants received any fertilizer and if so what kind?  What soil has been used in their pot?  They need lots of sunlight near a south window.  Don't move them around too much.  Try not to allow them to be in the direct sunlight until you know more.  Where were they living before given to you?  They are sedums and succulent...cactus family.  They store their own water.  Someone will be by to tell you exact names.  Try to find out their history from your friend!

Answer (score 1):

These plants are called succulents because they store water in their leaves. They need to be watered only after keeping the soil dry for a few days or even for a week. They also require rocky or gravelish or a bit of sandy soil. If they grow nicely in that soil in your pot, don't change it.

Basicaly, these are low maintainence plants that can be easily killed only by overwatering. In winter water them as rarely as possible because otherwise they become etiolated (their stems elongate and the space between leaves increases, thus making them not so pretty and not so healthy).

I don't know what the hanging plant is, but the little ones that make up most of the pot are Sedum. In the back I see something like a Sempervivum. For both Sedum and Semervivum, the exact species can't be determined without knowing further details like maximum heigth, colour of flowers, time of flowering, location, etc. Fortunately, they require similar care: lots of sunlight and small amounts of  water.